# Excepciones disponibles en python

Tags: python, excepciones

Estoy aprendiendo `python` y he llegado al punto de lanzar mis propias excepciones mediante la sentencia `raise`.

El problema está en que he buscado un listado con las excepciones disponibles y una descripción pero no he encontrado nada al respecto.

**¿Cuantas y cuales excepciones disponibles hay?**

Por ejemplo:

```
ZeroDivisionError: Se lanza al dividir por 0
```

¿Puedo crear mi propio nombre de excepción como `ZeroDivisionError` o siempre debo encapsular mi excepción dentro de una ya disponible en `python` y solo cambiar la descripción?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hasta donde yo se, no hay una traduccion oficial de la lista de *built-in exceptions* para python. Si el idioma no es un impedimento, aqui te dejo el [enlace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) en ingles. No es muy complicado de seguir y documenta tambien la jerarquia de las clases de excepcion.

Si que hay, no obstante, la traduccion de la documentacion oficial del control de errores [aqui](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/errors.html). Ahi podras encontrar respuesta a tu pregunta sobre si puedes crear tu propia excepcion. Pero basicamente, puedes hacerlo como quieras. O encapsular la ya disponible, o hacer una propia que haga lo mismo (no veo para que querrias hacer esto!), pero podrias hacerlo.